# Partial matching not working in this query

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Why does the following only match exact, and not partial?

```
    body: {
        query: {
            filtered: {
                filter: {
                    bool: {
                        should: [
                            { query: { match: { "name": "*"+searchterm+"*" }}},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`"*"+searchterm+"*"` should match any words that contains `searchterm`. ie,

```
item1
item2
0item
```

But it only matches words *exact* `searchterm` ie, only `item`. Why is this?

Comment: shouldn't it be query : {  regexp : { name : a regular expression } } ? you will find more examples in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html#_wildcard_and_regexp_queries

Comment: or maybe "query" : { "wildcard" : { "name" : text and wildcards * and ? } } ? if you do not wish to use regular expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `name` field is using default analyzer then the asterisk wildcard characters are dropped during analysis phase. Hence you always get results where `name` is exactly `sarchterm`. You need to use a [Wildcard query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) for matching any document where value of `name` field contains `searchterm`.

```
query: {
    filtered: {
        filter: {
            bool: {
                should: [
                    {
                        query: {
                            wildcard: {
                                "name": "*" + searchterm + "*" 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```